# Convert List<Property> To JObject

Tags: c#, json.net, linq-to-json

Consider this code:

```
var joWork = ((JObject) x).Properties()
    .Where(p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.String).ToList();
```

I end up with a `List<JProperty>`.

Is there a quick way using Linq or a JSON.NET function to convert that `List<JProperty>` object to a JObject without building a JObject from scratch in a loop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yup, you can just pass the list into the `JObject` constructor, and Json.NET will do the rest. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        JObject original = JObject.Parse("{ \"x\": \"a\", \"y\": \"b\", \"z\": 1 }");
        var properties = original
            .Properties()
            .Where(p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.String)
            .ToList();

        var recreated = new JObject(properties);
        Console.WriteLine(recreated);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "x": "a",
  "y": "b"
}
```

(The `z` property is missing because its value isn't a string.)

Comment: just curious. But would var obj = list.Cast<JObject>() work as well?

Comment: @PaulStoner: No, that's doing something entirely different - that would give an `IEnumerable<JObject>` which would throw an exception when you iterated over it because the values in the list are not references to instances of `JObject`.

Comment: Glad I didn't use that as an answer then. Thank you